# Messed up shoulder rig

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I'm working on my first character rig. I'm having a bit of trouble with the shoulder. The vertices, even though given 1.000 weight (and auto-normalize is on so it's definitely not dual-controlled) with shoulder.r it still doesn't rotate at a fixed angle with the bone. IDK if that's how rigs are supposed to work. Here's some pictures:[image: solid view][image: wireframe][image: weight paint]